# Netty: send messages to all (TCP) clients from outside the pipeline

Tags: java, netty

I'm migrating my "plain NIO" (= I used the packages from the JDK directly) TCP server to Netty 4.

I have threads that send messages to all clients, like health-checking packets, chat message broadcasts, direct chat messages to a single client, ... using a Collection of `SocketChannels` that I keep somewhere.

How do I do that in Netty? Would it be wise to simply share a ChannelGroup between one of the Netty handlers and the threads that need to send messages? The channel would look like this:

```
public class ChannelCollectorHandler extends ChannelInboundMessageHandlerAdapter<String> {

    private static final ChannelGroup channels = new DefaultChannelGroup();

    public SecureChatServerHandler(ChannelGroup channels) {
       this.channels = channels;
    }


    @Override
    public void channelActive(final ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        channels.add(ctx.channel());
    }

    ...
}
```

in all the threads I would then simply do:

```
channels.write(...);
```

will that work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes this will work without problems. ChannelGroup was designed for tasks like this.

Comment: Where will it start processing the outbound messages on the pipeline? Always at the "end" (so the first outbound handler) or ...?

Comment: Yes... It's the same as call Channel.write for each of them